# What's the syntax in Qat to find two words with no overlapping letter, taken from a given set of letters?

Tags: quinapalus

I know that `A=*/stonebrick` will find any word with letters taken from the set of letters `stonebrick`. I want two words taken from the same set of letters, with no overlap of letters between the two words.

What I thought would work is:

`AB=(*/stonebrick); A; B;`

The rationale is that both A and B are taken from the set of letters (but the concatenation itself doesn't have to be a word), and they each form a word. So for example it should find `A=stone, B=brick` in above.
But bracketed expression only accepts a single variable on the left. So, how can I do this?

From the comments, I realize there could be multiple interpretations of the question:

1. The set of letters may contain duplicated letters and the two words are allowed to use one copy each.
2. The set of letters may contain duplicated letters but only one copy should ever appear in the two words combined.
3. The set of letters does not contain duplicated letters.

I desire to have a generic solution like case 1. However, my actual use case is case 3, so answers that can answer at least case 3 is acceptable. And perhaps we can treat case 1 (harder) as a bonus. I assume solutions in case 2 will be similar, if not the same, to case 3.

Comment: It's not too bad with distinct letters, but double letters pose a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, noedne. I assume then your answer is working with individual letters, like `!=ABCDEFGHIJ`?

Comment: Yeah, but it's hard to extend this to allow repeated letters.

Comment: I guess you can go ahead and post that one. I updated the question to focus on that, but still allowing more general solutions.

Comment: Point about "bracketed expression only accepts a single variable on the left" ---- We could over-come this Point with a new variable C, like "C=(*/stonebrick); C=AB; A; B;" ---- But then, QAT can not have variables on the right !! It seems that, while QAT is impressive, it still has some incomplete functionality or unfinished areas !!

Answer (score 1):

If we restrict to the case where all the letters are distinct, then here is one strategy to find the pairs of words, with the disclaimers that the query is verbose and hard to modify, and the strategy requires multiple searches.

If our set of letters is `[stonebrick]`, then we can set the variable `A` to a single letter with `A=([stonebrick])`. Doing this for 10 variables `A` through `J` and setting `!=ABCDEFGHIJ` gives 10 distinct letters from our set. Finally, we can search for pairs of words of the desired lengths using `AB;CDEFGHIJ` for 2- and 8-letter words, all the way through `ABCDE;FGHIJ` for two 5-letter words, shifting the semicolon by one character for each search. For example, [this query](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=ABCD%3BEFGHIJ%3BA%3D%28%5Bstonebrick%5D%29%3BB%3D%28%5Bstonebrick%5D%29%3BC%3D%28%5Bstonebrick%5D%29%3BD%3D%28%5Bstonebrick%5D%29%3BE%3D%28%5Bstonebrick%5D%29%3BF%3D%28%5Bstonebrick%5D%29%3BG%3D%28%5Bstonebrick%5D%29%3BH%3D%28%5Bstonebrick%5D%29%3BI%3D%28%5Bstonebrick%5D%29%3BJ%3D%28%5Bstonebrick%5D%29%3B%21%3DABCDEFGHIJ&ent=Search&dict=4)

```
ABCD;EFGHIJ;A=([stonebrick]);B=([stonebrick]);C=([stonebrick]);D=([stonebrick]);E=([stonebrick]);F=([stonebrick]);G=([stonebrick]);H=([stonebrick]);I=([stonebrick]);J=([stonebrick]);!=ABCDEFGHIJ
```

gives the pairs of 4- and 6-letter words. If the two words are the same length, `A<F` can be used to force them to be in alphabetical order to avoid duplicates.

This method is not very convenient, and it is hard to extend it to allow repeated letters. It seems that Qat does not easily support this kind of query.

Comment: Whoa, that's so verbose, haha. Thanks for the effort writing that!

Comment: @justhalf Just a lot of copy/paste :)

Comment: I guess I again underdefine the spec, but you got it nonetheless. I meant to use the answer to this question to also include wild card letter, like AB=(*/stonebric.). But it's not doable with your answer.

Comment: Oh, actually we can still do that with [one wild card letter](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=ABCDE%3B*%2FFGHIJ%3BA%3D%28%5Bstonebric%5D%29%3BB%3D%28%5Bstonebric%5D%29%3BC%3D%28%5Bstonebric%5D%29%3BD%3D%28%5Bstonebric%5D%29%3BE%3D%28%5Bstonebric%5D%29%3BF%3D%28%5Bstonebric%5D%29%3BG%3D%28%5Bstonebric%5D%29%3BH%3D%28%5Bstonebric%5D%29%3BI%3D%28%5Bstonebric%5D%29%3B%21%3DABCDEFGHIJ%3B%7CJ%7C%3D1&ent=Search&dict=4). (for context, the motivation behind this question is to help solve [Qwordle](https://qwordle.bhat.ca/))

Comment: Apparently my previous Qat formula doesn't do what I thought it does. Qat can't anagram a set of variables.